# renaming wireless interface

Tags: wifi, rename, interface

I know I can rename my wireless interface with ip link set  name , but when I do other programs won't identify the new name, namely wash, and then if I run iwconfig  down I can't get systemctl won't restart NetworkManager. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add to you question the actual command you are running to rename the interface and the error you get from `iwconfig`. Maybe also state what you are trying to achieve or why you are renaming the interface, because there might be other solutions.

Comment: I'm running ```sudo ip link set wlp2s0 name mon0``` I want to rename the interface because it is a pain to type wlp2s0 over and over.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303099/how-to-change-the-name-of-wireless-interface